# How to make a struct component a variable?

Tags: c#, list

Not sure I am asking this right or this even possible.
I feel to explain my question it is best to ask right in the code at the relevant places so please see my comments in the snippet below.

I wonder how to achieve this without building a new list of values for each I iteration. I feel this should not be necessary.

The bigger picture of this loop is to plot individual dimensions of 3D points to three new 2D plots of these. Hope that makes sense.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // 3 iterations (X,Y;Z)
{           
    // what here? how to make the data component of Vector3D a variable
    for (int k = 0; k <= Points.Count - 1; k++)
    {
        Vector2D TL = new Vector2D();

        TL.x = ((1 / (float)FrameCount.Sum()) * k);
        TL.y = Points[k].x;      // on i = 0 want Points[k].x
                                 // on i = 1 want Points[k].y
                                 // on i = 2 want Points[k].z

        TimelinePoints.Add(TL); // just collect to a flat list for now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to have an array of extraction functions that you could apply to points. You can then use the LINQ `Select` overload that accepts a `Func<TInput, int, TOutput>` to generate a sequence of the values you want to add, and add it to `TimeLinePoints` that way.

```
// Possibly store this in a static variable somewhere
var extractors = new Func<Point, float>[] { p => p.x, p => p.y, p => p.z };

// Just do this once; store the result as a float for simplicity when dividing later.
float frameSum = FrameCount.Sum();
foreach (var extractor in extractors)
{
    TimeLinePoints.AddRange(Points.Select((point, index) =>
        new Vector2D(index / frameSum, extractor(point));
}
```

(You could go even further using `SelectMany` potentially, but that's where I'd start...)

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. Going to dig this now to fully understand what is going on ;) Have a nice sunday.

Answer (score 4):

A considerably more pedestrian approach compared to Jon Skeet's answer would be to modify the `Point` struct to include an indexer, assuming that is an option:

```
public struct Point
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;

  public float this[int index]
  {
    get
    {
      switch (index)
      {
        case 0:
        return x;
        case 1:
        return y;
        case 2:
        return z;
        default:
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
      }
    }
    set
    {
      switch (index)
      {
        case 0:
        x = value;
        break;
        case 1:
        y = value;
        break;
        case 2:
        z = value;
        break;
        default:
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could assign the proper field according to the value of your loop counter, like so:

```
for (int k = 0; k < Points.Count; k++)
{
    Vector2D TL = new Vector2D();

    TL.x = ((1 / (float)FrameCount.Sum()) * k);
    TL.y = Points[k][i];

    TimelinePoints.Add(TL); // just collect to a flat list for now
}
```

Comment: While will stick with Jon Skeet's answer, this is actually better understandable for me. Thank you for showing this different approach and that this is possible with a struct, definitely going to dig it too. Very confident this will help me with other stuff. cheers

Answer (score 3):

The alternate way is to use `Linq` to archive this:

```
Points
    //foreach point create 3 Vector2D with X, Y and Z coordinate
    .SelectMany((p, index) => new []
    { 
        new Vector2D(index / frameSum, p.X), 
        new Vector2D(index / frameSum, p.Y), 
        new Vector2D(index / frameSum, p.Z) 
    })
    //unfurl IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Vector2D>> to IEnumerable<Vector2D>
    .Select(v => v) 
    .ToList();
```

Comment: you guys killing me, there is no loop at all? so much new stuff to learn :) i see this is the SelectMany Jon Skeet mentioned in his answer. nice, thanks for showing! Although this is zipping all dimensions into the list but i need first all x values then y, then z. but anyway this is a nice example i can work with to learn and maybe i will need just that for something else. thanks!